# Using node.js in production?

Tags: javascript, node.js

To those in the business of web development, is `node.js` ready for production use? How reliable is it?

Comment: Node is still pretty young, but surprisingly stable. I wouldn't use it for a major corporation's main page, but I'd use it for adding features to a corporate server. Even Mozilla has been playing with using Jaegermonkey instead of v8, and that means something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js is absolutely ready for production in terms of things like system stability, power, and performance.  However, some features might still change before version 1, and there are a lot of mature tools on other platforms that don't quite exist yet for node (though new things are popping up on node every day).

Several businesses are already using node.js in production.  For a few, check out https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node

Comment: And be cautious which features you use. For example MemoryStore still leaks memory in the lastest available version.

Answer (score 3):

outloud.fm uses it, seems to work pretty well

I don't run that site though, so I can't speak from personal experience

Answer (score -1):

Does it do what you want?

Does it run like you want it to without crashing for your needs?

Then it's production use ready.

Comment: any reason for downvotes? This is a solid pragmatic approach?

Comment: @Raynos The downvote probably happened because it is a completely unhelpful answer.  The questions were "Is it production ready?" and "Is it reliable?" and the above answer was effectively, "Well, what do you think?"

Comment: @Thom ~ Bear in mind that sometimes we just need someone to ask us "well, what do you think" and then we can figure out the answer that is locked in our heads. Notice I wasn't adverse to getting downvoted, Raynos just was curious wth. But tbh, if the runtime does what you need and accomplishes the feat in a sufficiently small amount of time and doesn't crash, then the product is suited for production use. That would be the definition of production ready. You'll notice that Microsoft.NET has had a few iterations and SPs, so obviously it ain't perfect, but people use it every day. ;)

Comment: He probably wants to know if node.js is production ready before start developing "seriously" a certain app. So he can't answer these questions.

Comment: @Ixx I disagree entirely. It took me all of two days of reading about node before I knew what the major limitations were. And that was before 0.5.